# What could cause forbidden 403 after successful SSL handshake?

Tags: ssl, https

I have a question about an TLS connection I am making inside my Java application to an external party.

The TLS handshake seems to finish without any issues. (See log below).
But I still get a 403 forbidden from the web server I am trying to hit.

Because the SSL handshake has finished does it means I can rule out certificates as being the problem? i.e. Is it more likely to be like a firewall blocking me on the other side?

Also can anyone think of anything else I can do on my side to get more information about why things might be going wrong? I ask this question because at the moment I feel like I have exhausted all avenues of investigation.

thanks

```
[api-blah-v1-132].http.requester.apiHttpblahRequestConfig.worker(5), READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 2704
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1489311495 bytes = { 24, 166, 5, 115, 96, 245, 87, 168, 201, 0, 140, 169, 246, 167, 17, 130, 35, 82, 180, 20, 78, 118, 197, 139, 115, 85, 149, 249 }
Session ID:  {240, 31, 0, 0, 187, 150, 112, 197, 105, 66, 166, 30, 38, 101, 157, 77, 70, 251, 210, 109, 66, 5, 150, 39, 144, 252, 165, 154, 98, 139, 28, 247}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: 24:d2:f9:be:4f:9b:34:9d:97:0a:87:7e:b3:00:a5:3b:9e:fd:13:83:1b:7c:57:f5
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-5, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=myComppany.dns.com.au
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 20347157146520353095861639278208184247286986690713431491420841394784858170529375449223849853534354840929149706378303297947541892423057001636130580267149963843615721783983566141638311949114700827164868954418508313798333746643037746007234047993830271943749361746071066892915327273997666547176023092823087128341412638685856170738104070682226405621117015097115212087323270530842662099589771387988512876505892653094995664532977115190036204521785829075338794419227119436542735750611752914553559131212700916410969902308936242124816342527509957358809361641507658744635443218654637212447896897323865396709669621261450063512703
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue May 16 10:07:21 AEST 2017,
               To: Thu May 16 10:07:20 AEST 2019]
  Issuer: CN=EDS_RootCA
  SerialNumber: [    3f6b1b9d 4e6a8491 479d4580 318d46b6]
Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.1 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 4F 30 4D 80 10 1F 88   3D 3B E3 7C 8A 45 C0 4C  .O0M....=;...E.L
0010: 36 EF 64 C8 23 A5 A1 27   30 25 31 23 30 21 06 03  6.d.#..'0%1#0!..
0020: 55 04 03 1E 1A 00 45 00   44 00 53 00 5F 00 56 00  U.....E.D.S._.
0030: 52 00 5F 00 52 00 6F 00   6F 00 74 00 43 00 41 82  ._.R.o.o.t.C.A.
0040: 10 1F E5 AA 89 7F E6 11   82 4D FE D1 DB FA F4 7E  .........M......
0050: 8D                                                 .
]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 26 94 B7 78 21 EC 60 24   28 6E 7D C0 93 43 7A F8  &..x!.`$(n...Cz.
0010: 27 E8 BF 36 E1 B9 6E 41   4F 3B B7 7D 48 FB F4 77  '..6..nAO;..H..w
0020: 56 30 85 5E C1 5E 73 1A   79 7A B8 7F 48 DE 85 2F  V0.^.^s.yz..H../
0030: 03 93 8F 78 15 28 65 4D   78 E1 DE 83 83 10 B0 97  ...x.(eMx.......
0040: 0C F2 8E D3 E7 E3 16 8E   1C C8 0D 6D 04 B9 64 81  ...........m..d.
0050: 59 B1 34 D7 2E 86 1C E0   CD D7 19 8E 7C 00 CA CD  Y.4.............
0060: A5 3D 37 F0 31 24 E6 DC   01 66 9C D2 6A 25 FE 0A  .=7.1$...f..j%..
0070: F9 02 B7 41 17 38 BA 74   05 34 EC 5D 3D DB 20 CB  ...A.8.t.4.]=. .
]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE>
<CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US>
<CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=thawte Primary Root CA, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE>
<CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE>
<CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US>
<CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=Washington, C=US>
<CN=SercoTcsRootCA>
<CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=Washington, C=US>
<CN=Microsoft Root Authority, OU=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp.>
<CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=Tenix IMES CA>
<CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority, DC=microsoft, DC=com>
<CN=SercoTcsRootCA, DC=, DC=ap, DC=ser, DC=com>
<CN=EDS__RootCA>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
[api-blah-v1-132].http.requester.apiHttpblahRequestConfig.worker(5), WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 304
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 B3 1D 9D 31 6C 7D   0D D7 92 73 03 F0 6D 84  .....1l....s..m.
0010: 4D 6C BB 52 D7 26 C1 B0   58 82 90 23 29 DB AC 1C  Ml.R.&..X..#)...
0020: DA 19 E1 6C A0 63 31 22   0D 39 05 FD 92 A6 43 A6  ...l.c1".9....C.
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 59 C5 17 07 63 E9 79 F6   63 5A 7A 43 66 8D 1C B2  Y...c.y.cZzCf...
0010: 60 6C 4A CF E4 86 9A 81   A2 2B C6 F0 5E 76 6A 93  `lJ......+..^vj.
Server Nonce:
0000: 59 C5 17 07 18 A6 05 73   60 F5 57 A8 C9 00 8C A9  Y......s`.W.....
0010: F6 A7 11 82 23 52 B4 14   4E 76 C5 8B 73 55 95 F9  ....#R..Nv..sU..
Master Secret:
0000: 74 FC 19 66 31 63 EB 6D   77 D0 90 35 89 AF 5E 2D  t..f1c.mw..5..^-
0010: 92 07 CD 77 18 D4 8A B0   A4 ED D6 87 79 EC BA DC  ...w........y...
0020: B5 85 EF BF 6E 44 60 08   93 10 18 89 42 37 58 45  ....nD`.....B7XE
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: C1 EA 83 8C DB D9 FC 4D   BA B3 F0 CA 63 98 5F 3E  .......M....c._>
0010: 5B E0 87 F0                                        [...
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 8C 01 99 66 54 26 87 2A   16 96 6F 6B 96 8A F3 6B  ...fT&.*..ok...k
0010: 84 8C 9E D9                                        ....
Client write key:
0000: 96 E6 14 E2 F6 85 B8 93   51 90 2C CA 86 05 0F FE  ........Q.,.....
Server write key:
0000: 96 4C 43 E0 3A FB 05 72   3B 91 6B DB D8 1D 41 67  .LC.:..r;.k...Ag
Client write IV:
0000: BB AA 2B 91 63 10 62 EA   B6 8E 2D 48 DD 8A 6C EE  ..+.c.b...-H..l.
Server write IV:
0000: 25 30 3F 0A 96 D4 D9 1B   F2 B1 92 29 62 CD 0D 4D  %0?........)b..M
[api-blah-v1-132].http.requester.apiHttpblahRequestConfig.worker(5), WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 32
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 232, 153, 163, 243, 22, 33, 213, 172, 119, 46, 247, 107 }
***
[api-blah-v1-132].http.requester.apiHttpblahRequestConfig.worker(5), WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
[api-blah-v1-132].http.requester.apiHttpblahRequestConfig.worker(5), READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 32
[api-blah-v1-132].http.requester.apiHttpblahRequestConfig.worker(5), READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 232, 126, 65, 13, 112, 166, 63, 121, 201, 0, 57, 110 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-5, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
WARN  2017-09-22 23:58:32,052 [[api-blah-v1-132].apiHttpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now\norg.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response code 403 mapped as failure.\n
```

Answer (score 2):

> Because the SSL handshake has finished does it means I can rule out certificates as being the problem?

Yes.

> i.e. Is it more likely to be like a firewall blocking me on the other side?

No.

It is the Web server denying you permission to access the requested resource. There is no reason why a successful TLS handshake alone should permit you that access. It is up to the Web server who can access what.

Comment: And what's some examples as to why the web server would do that is?

Comment: And also do I know from the 403 whether I have I passed the company's firewall?

Comment: You know your web server 's access policies a lot better than I do. If you got the 403 your TLS and firewall penetration is working perfectly. The 403 was transmitted via HTTPS, and HTTPS works over TLS, and TLS works over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked at this more. I discovered that you have to be very careful with reading the output posted.

Although the handshake reports as successful there is a message in the handshake as follows. This basically means that the handshake failed although the first packet may have been sent.

Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication

There was a problem with my keystore and that was that it did not have the certificate of the issuer in it.

Comment: It means that *authentication* failed, which occurs *after* the handshake. The client didn't send a certificate, the server looked for the client certificate, didn't find one, and closed the connection. Not sending a client certificate isn't an error in TLS itself. The message is inside the handshake but the consequence occurs afterwards. This is part of the application, not part of TLS, or even HTTPS. It is exactly as I said. 'The Web server is denying you permission ot access the requested resource.'

Comment: cool that for that clarification. It helps me understand the handshake a lot better. I thought the handshake would fail if it couldn't find the right certificatate.